# Php SoapClient is very slow on first connection

Tags: php, caching, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I use php `SoapClient` to call M3 (Movex) webservices, stored on our internal server. My Symfony 3.4 project which does the calls is on another internal linux server.

I noticed that the initialization of the soap client is very slow (2-3 minutes) when it's done **after a long time without using it** (several hours). For example, it occurs the morning, when I test my project for the first time of the day. But I have no problem for every initializations and calls done after several minutes (responds in 500ms).

Because of the 1st init takes several minutes, my nginx server returns a 504 gateway time-out error after 1 minute.

The webservices urls are in HTTPS and we use SSL certificates. We also had to authenticate with a login and a password. I use a session cookie, available for 8 hours, that I add in the HTTP request header. We don't use a proxy.

I think it's a **cache problem**. When I'm using SoapUI, I don't have the problem, the webservice responds very fastly.

Here is the configuration of the soap extension in my php.ini :

[image]

Here is my soap client init :

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://my-domain.com:55080/my-webservice?wsdl", array(
  'login'     => $login,
  'password'  => $pwd,
  'trace'     => true,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => ['header' => 'cookie: ' . $cookie]
  ))
));
```

I tried to add `'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY` in the options but it's worse, every time I'm using it, it's very slow.

Here are the logs to see where the problem occurs (look at lines 3 and 4 -> 2 minutes) :

```
01/10/19 09:58:06 ------- Get Customer -------
01/10/19 09:58:06 - Cookie exists -> send it in the request
01/10/19 09:58:06 - BEGIN Init soap client
01/10/19 10:00:07 - END Init soap client
01/10/19 10:00:07 - BEGIN client->GetCustomerData
01/10/19 10:00:07 - END client->GetCustomerData
01/10/19 10:00:07 ------- END Get Customer -------
```

When I test it again after several minutes (no problem, done in the same second) :

```
01/10/19 10:03:52 ------- Get Customer -------
01/10/19 10:03:52 - Cookie exists -> send it in the request
01/10/19 10:03:52 - BEGIN Init soap client
01/10/19 10:03:52 - END Init soap client
01/10/19 10:03:52 - BEGIN client->GetCustomerData
01/10/19 10:03:52 - END client->GetCustomerData
01/10/19 10:03:52 ------- END Get Customer -------
```

Comment: Can you check if there are references to XSD definitions / XSD files in your WSDL filem that are hostet on W3C servers? The w3c has set an delay on definitions because of excessive traffic: https://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/ You can download these definitions and host them on your own server. When you do so, you have to rewrite the wsdl file and host it on your own server, too. Another solution could be setting up your soap client with a different user agent in the options. Just disguise your client as browser and the delay is gone.
Could be one reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that kind of urls `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` ? I have this too `xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"` and a lot of urls from `http://schemas.lawson.com/...` but this namespace doesn't work.

Comment: @Marcel I'm interested in your 2nd solution. Can you write me how can I disguise my client as a browser please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the wsdl file and put it on the same server than my project solved the problem.

I don't have a delay during the initialization of the soap client. And I disabled the cache too. It works perfectly now.

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ."/path-to/file.xml", array(
  'login'      => $login,
  'password'   => $pwd,
  'trace'      => true,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => ['header' => 'cookie: ' . $cookie]
  ))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question in your comments you can try to disguise your soap client as a browser. This might be a possible solution. There 's no garanty, that this is the one and only solution. ;)

```
// options
$wsdl = 'https://your.service.url.here?wsdl';

$options = [
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'connection_timeout' => 30,
    'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/1.0N (Windows)',
];

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    // more logic here
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I will test it. But I don't add `WSDL_CACHE_NONE` because it slows down my requests even more.

Comment: This is just a copy and paste issue. ;) You can try the  `WSDL_CACHE_DISK`, `WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY` or `WSDL_CACHE_BOTH` options.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, the init is still very slow with a custom user agent.